# HW Help - Reading from file character by character C++

Tags: c++

For a project I am currently working on, I have to read from a file and depending on the certain character in the file, output either a 1 or 0 to an array.

So here is an example of file input:

```
*  *   *
*  *  * 
** ** **
 ***   *
```

And here is the function I have written to handle this:

```
void input (int cellGrid[][MAX]) //takes info from a .txt and puts it into an array
{
ifstream infile; //declare a file variable
int row;
int column;
int number;
infile.open("life.txt"); //open a file


while(infile>>row>>column) { //inserts bacteria places into array
cout << row << " " << column << endl;

cellGrid[row][column]=1; //makes it equal one if bacteria is present
}

infile.close(); //closes file
}
```

My thinking was that the function needs to see if there is a character that exists and if so, place a 1 in its respective position ([row][column]) in the array. However with this current code, nothing is input into my array.

Comment: The code you have for reading from `infile` doesn't seem to match your example input file at all. Your code attempts to read integers, but there are no integers in your input file.

Comment: Think on what number you would get from trying to read `*` as an integer. Consider using `std::getline` to get a line and counting the characters on the line to get the number of columns. Loop that until you can't read anymore and you know how many rows. Now you can build a cell array.

Comment: It's probably better to use `std::vector` to store lines than some arbitrary fixed-size C-style array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in C++ use `std::vector` wherever possible.

### Array example:

You have to go through the file and record position of each `*`. Then set it to 1 for that position. Something like the following (we use `getline` and `i` as counter for rows, then we loop through the line using `j` as counter for columns):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void input(int cellGrid[][100]) {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("life.txt");

    int i = 0;
    for (string line; getline(infile, line); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < line.size(); ++j) {
            if (line[j] == '*') {
                cellGrid[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

### Vector example #1:

Here you can find a solution using `std::vector`. It will be always in a size `rows x columns`. One thing it requires is to pass default constructed `vector` and not constructed with `vector(size_type count);` c-tor. You can write your own version that doesn't have this problem:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void input(vector<vector<int>> &cellGrid) {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("life.txt");

    int i = 0;
    for (string line; getline(infile, line); ++i)
    {
        cellGrid.push_back(vector<int>(line.size()));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < line.size(); ++j) {
            if (line[j] == '*') {
                cellGrid[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    infile.close();
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> cellGrid;
    vector<vector<int>> cellGrid2(100);
    input(cellGrid);
    //input(cellGrid2); - THIS WILL THROW AN EXCEPTION
    return 0;
}
```

### Vector example #2:

It would be even better for you function to return a newly created and populated `vector`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> input() {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("life.txt");
    vector<vector<int>> cell_grid;

    int i = 0;
    for (string line; getline(infile, line); ++i)
    {
        cell_grid.push_back(vector<int>(line.size()));
        for (size_t j = 0; j < line.size(); ++j) {
            if (line[j] == '*') {
                cell_grid[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    infile.close();
    return cell_grid;
}

int main() {
    auto vec = input();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The solution you posted works but what if there are more than 100 columns? Is it possible to dynamically allocate a 2D array?

Comment: @RishavSinha edited with an example that returns a `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

My thinking goes like this:

```
set row to 0
while can read a line from file
    set column to 0
    for each character on line
        if character  is '*'
            set cellGrid(row,column) to 1
        else
            set cellGrid(row,column) to 0
        increment column
    increment row
```

You may want additional logic to trap row or column trying to go out of bounds or characters that aren't ' ' or '*'.